# What is the command to show the product of two integers or the square root of an integer positivo?

Tags: math-mode

LaTeX has a command that shows the Division Algorithm:

```
$$\opdiv{42}{75}$$
```

Is there a command to show the product of two integers or the square root of an integer?
[image]

Comment: How about `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xlop}
\begin{document}
\opmul{453}{1001205}
\end{document}`

Comment: Also, p.46 of the `xlop` documentation indicates anticipated **future** support for `\oproot` and `\opsqrt`; however, none exists at present in the package.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes This is definitely an answer.  Could you please make it one?

Comment: Since nobody has mentioned it yet, please note that using `$$<stuff>$$` results in TeX display math. For LaTeX it's better to use `\[<stuff\]` and friends. You may find out more about which friends LaTeX has by reading the AMS math documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `xlop` package already provides the ability to show the algorithm of multiplication.  Here is an example:

```
\documentclass{article} 
\usepackage{xlop} 
\begin{document} 
\opmul{453}{1001205} 
\end{document}
```

[image]

As to square roots, I was unable to locate anything to do it.  However, p.46 of the `xlop` V0.25 documentation indicates that it is their intent to introduce such support in the future.  See the bottom of the attached excerpt.

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Version 0.26 (current CTAN version today) supports square root with \opsqrt macro. This version gives also the \opgfsqrt which display an operation to extract square root ('gf' stand for grand father since my grand father was proud to had learned this method... in fact this method is ugly :-) Newton, for instance, is far better):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{xlop}

\begin{document}
\opsqrt{42}{a}
$\sqrt{42}\approx \opprint{a}$
\par\vspace{5mm}
\opgfsqrt{42}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Line \opsqrt{42}{a} shows a compilation error with Miktex (xlop 2009/12/02 out of .log)  today , and same error with overleaf.com.

Comment: Miktex did not update to version 0.26, it remained at 0.25.

Comment: Today, MikTeX has just updated xlop to version 0.26.