# How to write multiplication of two numbers in column form?

Tags: code

I need your help in transforming the product of two numbers written in row format into column format. For instance, how can I write `3 x 3 = 9` in column form like this:

```
  3
x 3
___
  9
```

Comment: See the `xlop` package, or this question: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248684/what-is-the-command-to-show-the-product-of-two-integers-or-the-square-root-of-an

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Two other ways to do it. I used the rules of `booktabs` for a better vertical spacing:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{booktabs}

\begin{document}

\[ \begin{matrix*}[r]
   3 \\
   {}\times 3\\
   \midrule
   9
\end{matrix*}
\]
\bigskip

\[ \begin{aligned}
     3 & \;\\
   {}\times 3\\
   \midrule
   9
\end{aligned}
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Using an `array` environment should be enough:

```
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\[
\begin{array}{@{}r@{}}
   3 \\
   {}\times 3\\
   \hline
   9
\end{array}
\]
\end{document}
```