# Is typesetting of elementary arithmetic exercises without tables or TikZ possible?

Tags: exercises, arithmetic

Is there a way to avoid using TikZ or tables typesetting elementary arithmetic exercises like these:

[image]

I would like to have a some kind of a placeholder character and the distance between numbers have to be the same.

Comment: Are you looking for the `xlop` package?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/248684/what-is-the-command-to-show-the-product-of-two-integers-or-the-square-root-of-an  Or maybe this? https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/309961/pencil-and-paper-subtraction-in-latex

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes Looks good, but this package seems even to calculate the results and I'd like to be able to leave some digits out, so it's an exercise and not a complete solution.

Comment: Not sure why you want to avoid "tables" (`tabular`??).  This is similar to `tabular` approach: `\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tabstackengine}
\newcommand\textcdot{\raisebox{.5\dimexpr\ht\strutbox-\dp\strutbox}{.}}
\begin{document}
\texttt{\tabbedShortstack[r]{
928\textcdot58\\
\TABrule\\
 4640~\\
  7424\\
\TABrule\\
 53824
}}
\end{document}`  What is it that is undesirable here?

Comment: You could put each digit centered in a fixed size box.See https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/168281/how-to-draw-a-chessboard-with-numbers

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes The syntax is quite messy, so I would prefer John's solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using tables cannot be avoided, but you can hide them to the user.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{xparse,array,booktabs}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\NewDocumentCommand{\multiplication}{mmmm}
 {% #1 = first factor, #2 = second factor, #3 = steps, #4 = result
  \gemir_mult:nnnn { #1 } { #2 } { #3 } { #4 }
 }

\seq_new:N \l__gemir_mult_steps_in_seq
\seq_new:N \l__gemir_mult_steps_out_seq

\cs_new_protected:Nn \gemir_mult:nnnn
 {
  \seq_set_split:Nnn \l__gemir_mult_steps_in_seq { \\ } { #3 }
  \seq_clear:N \l__gemir_mult_steps_out_seq
  % add padding to the steps
  \seq_indexed_map_function:NN \l__gemir_mult_steps_in_seq \__gemir_mult_pad:nn
  % typeset the table
  \begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
  \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__gemir_mult_box:n
  \__gemir_mult_box:n { \cdot }
  \tl_map_function:nN { #2 } \__gemir_mult_box:n
  \\
  \midrule
  \seq_map_function:NN \l__gemir_mult_steps_out_seq \__gemir_mult_step:n
  \midrule
  \tl_map_function:nN { #4 } \__gemir_mult_box:n
  \end{tabular}
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gemir_mult_pad:nn
 {
  \seq_put_right:Nx \l__gemir_mult_steps_out_seq
   {
    #2
    \prg_replicate:nn { \seq_count:N \l__gemir_mult_steps_in_seq - #1 } { \scan_stop: }
   }
 }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gemir_mult_box:n
 {
  \makebox[1em]{$\str_if_eq:nnTF { #1 } { ? } { \_ } { #1 }$}
 }
\cs_new_protected:Nn \__gemir_mult_step:n { \tl_map_function:nN { #1 } \__gemir_mult_box:n \\ }

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}

\multiplication{928}{58}{4640\\7424}{53824}\qquad
\multiplication{928}{58}{4?40\\7424}{53?24}

\end{document}
```

A `?` means a blank in the table.

[image]